# Create directory structure in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to create directory structure based on year, month and julian day as given below.

```
/home/applications/app_name/year/month/julian day
e.g.: /home/applications/app_name/2016/June/155
```

I am writting a script to create such directories for next entire month and script will be scheduled monthly. if I am running the script on 01st of June, script should create all directories for month of July.

```
e.g: /home/applications/app_name/2016/July/(julian days)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What did you tried so far, please share some of the code!

Comment: Where is your script?

Comment: And you need to actually ask a question.

Comment: What problem do you want to solve: creating several directories in batch or computing their names based on your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
current_year=$(date +%Y)
next_month=$(($(date +%m) + 1))
locale_next_month=$(date -d$current_year/$next_month/1 +%B)

for day_of_month in $(seq 1 31)
do
  if day_of_year=$(date -d$current_year/$next_month/$day_of_month +%j 2> /dev/null)
  then
    mkdir -p /home/applications/app_name/$current_year/$locale_next_month/$day_of_year
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks..This is what I was looking for ..Thanks much..it worked.